# Xmgrace delete specific row in dataset via batch file

Tags: xmgrace

I want to delete the first row of dataset. I tried through Commands window (`Window`>`Commands`) by typing any:

```
S0[2][0]
S0[1][0]
S0[1][1]
S0[1:2][1]
```

But I got errors:

```
[Error] syntax error: S0[2][0]
[Error] syntax error: S0[1][0]
[Error] syntax error: S0[1][1]
[Error] syntax error: S0[1:2][1]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [xmgr commands](https://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/commands.html#setops), this is achieved with command `DROP`

> - setnum DROP expr, expr
> - graphno.setnum DROP expr, expr
>
> Drop points in setnum (or graphno.setnum). The parameters give the index of the first and last points to drop, respectively.

Comment: Good job! Feel free to accept your own answer. You won't get any rep, but it may help others in the future.